# ReadInnerXml Out Of Memory

Tags: c#, xmlreader

While parsing large data in an xml file (about 1GB) the concept was to write the various elements to seperate temporary files. Each of those files could then be processed later while being able to initially advertise the overall content of the file to the end user. The user may select only a few of the elements for further processing. This is accomplished by calling the reader's ReadInnerXml() method which returns a string which in turn is easilly provided to a SteamWriter. However when an exception results such as an out of memory error I am uncertain as to if (1) I can skip past and read other (hopefully smaller) elements and (2) can I not avoid a string completely and somehow write the xml element to a temporary file without having to consume so much physical memory using the string?

Comment: `XmlWriter.WriteNode` has an overload that accepts an `XmlReader`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks will look into that immediately.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Works perfectly, many thanks.

Comment: It turns out that the xml node that was causing an out of memory error was about 1.8GB in size.

Comment: That's all rather impractical.  Use Project > Properties > Build tab, untick the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox.  You don't prefer it.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, but I never use that "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox. Bit confused, how is it related to my question?